# How to change Windows 8 Storage Pool Resiliency type?

Tags: windows-8, storage-spaces, storage-pool

After creating a number of Storage Spaces in Windows 8 how can you later change the Storage Space resiliency type to something different? So far the only work around I have found is to create a new Storage Space and copy all files over to it.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Storage Spaces FAQ](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11382.storage-spaces-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx#What_properties_can_I_change_after_creating_a_storage_space) from TechNet you cannot change resiliency once a storage space has been created:

> What properties can I change after creating a storage space?
>
> Upon creating a storage space, certain fundamental properties are
>   locked in place. These fundamental properties include the provisioning
>   type (thin or fixed), the *resiliency type* (simple, mirror, or parity),
>   the number of columns the storage space striping requires, and the
>   striping interleave.
>
> After creating a storage space, you can change properties that do not
>   affect fundamental characteristics, such as the size of the storage
>   space and its name.